# Проблема с json получение фото инстаграмм

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, instagram

Подскажите как решить эту проблему, у меня при работе с json одна и та же ошибка.
Вот программа, что скачивает фото с инстаграма

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import re
import sys

import requests

def getID(username):
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/{}"

    r = requests.get(url.format(username))

    html = r.text

    if r.ok:
        return re.findall('"id":"(.*?)",', html)[0]

    else:
        print("\033[91m✘ Invalid username\033[0m")
        sys.exit()


def fetchDP(userID):
    url = "https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/{}/info/"

    r = requests.get(url.format(userID))

    if r.ok:
        data = r.json()
        return data['user']['hd_profile_pic_url_info']['url']

    else:
        print("\033[91m✘ Cannot find user ID \033[0m")
        sys.exit()


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Download any users Instagram display picture/profile picture in full quality")

    parser.add_argument('username', action="store", help="username of the Instagram user")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    username = args.username

    user_id = getID(username)
    file_url = fetchDP(user_id)
    fname = username + ".jpg"

    r = requests.get(file_url, stream=True)
    if r.ok:
        with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
            print("\033[92m✔ Downloaded:\033[0m {}".format(fname))
    else:
        print("Cannot make connection to download image")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

но когда я запускаю выдает такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
C:\Users\red.iguana\Desktop\Practice\practice_3>python qqq.py bohvffhb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qqq.py", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "qqq.py", line 48, in main
    file_url = fetchDP(user_id)
  File "qqq.py", line 29, in fetchDP
    data = r.json()
  File "C:\Users\red.iguana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\red.iguana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\red.iguana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\red.iguana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Подскажите как решить проблему

```
C:\Users\red.iguana\Desktop\Practice\practice_3>python qqq.py bohvffhb
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root">\n    <head>\n        <meta ch'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qqq.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
  File "qqq.py", line 49, in main
    file_url = fetchDP(user_id)
  File "qqq.py", line 30, in fetchDP
    data = r.json()
  File "C:\Users\red.iguana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\red.iguana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\red.iguana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\red.iguana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки в вопрос

Comment: @gil9red добавил

Comment: Перед `data = r.json()` добавьте `print(r.content[:100])` и покажите результат. Мне кажется вам не json вернулся

Comment: @gil9red добавил

Comment: Ну да, вам пришел html, поэтому и ошибка при парсинге. Выведите полностью тот html и посмотрите что в нем написано. Мб какая-нибудь ошибка. Кст, перед `print(r.content[:100])` добавьте `print(r.status_code)`. Какой код вам вернулся?

Comment: @gil9red 200 код

Comment: @gil9red не подскажите как можно фиксануть?

Comment: Легко -- изучаете что пришло в ответе. Возможно там будет описание ошибки. Если нет, то возможно вы неправильно оформляетесь запрос к `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/{}/info/`. Не знаю откуда вы его взяли, но возможно нужно какие-нибудь заголовки заполнять или параметры. Например `api_key` или какой-нибудь токен. Ну и поищите модули для работы с api инстаграмма, и не создавайте велосипеды